# Minumum value of a list isn't compariable with a double value

Tags: c#

```
if (b.BooksList[ID].BookPrices.Min== b.BooksList[ID].BookPrices[i])
```

cannot be compared. `BookPrices[]` is a list of doubles.

Error:
`Error  11  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'double'`

Comment: As a side note, you should never store currency amounts as double, and you should never compare doubles for equality. Those things are fraught with little problems. You should use `decimal` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the parenthesis on your call to `Min()`.

Whenever the words "method group" appear in an error message, it's time to go looking for missing parenthesis on a function call.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it was a method. How come C# suggested me using the propety `Min`?

Comment: I don't know who suggested that Min was a property, but it's not. It's an extension method in `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Visual Studio likely didn't suggest Min as a property. However, if you just accept the Intellisense suggestion (`Min`) with pressing Enter or Tab, it won't insert the parentheses by itself. I'd rather suggest to accept Intellisense by pressing the opening bracket for functions (purple brick), which will train you to automatically do *the right thing* in the future without thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if (b.BooksList[ID].BookPrices.Min()== b.BooksList[ID].BookPrices[i])
```